# how do i check and create a directory in bash

Tags: linux, bash

so, i'm going to check whether a directory exists or not, if not, then the script is going to create one. and here is the code:

```
APPLICATION_DATA_DIRECTORY="~/.directorychecker/"
APPLICATION_DATA_DIRECTORY_CREATE="~/.directorychecker/"
CHECK_APPLICATION_DATA_DIRECTORY()
{
    if [ -d "$APPLICATION_DATA_DIRECTORY" ]
    then
    echo "directory exists"
    else
    mkdir $APPLICATION_DATA_DIRECTORY_CREATE
    echo "directory is NOT exist, but now created"
    fi
} 

CHECK_APPLICATION_DATA_DIRECTORY
```

however, while the folder check mechanism runs smoothly, the folder creation mechanism don't want to run and returns

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `~/.directorychecker/': No such file or directory
```

i really got no idea on making it work since the script seems fine

does anybody here had the same problem and solution? any answer will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You're "checking for directory" just fine.  The problem is the tilde.  The solution is to substitute `${HOME}`.  Please be sure to "upvote" and accept Basile Starynkevitch's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Should be

```
 APPLICATION_DATA_DIRECTORY="$HOME/.directorychecker/"
```

etc...

Otherwise you are creating a directory whose name starts with `~` which is a bad thing. Your use of `~` as the first character of a string is not expanded to `$HOME`

BTW, putting (temporarily, for debugging purpose) `#!/bin/bash -xv` as the first line of your script would have helped you find that bug.